# Derived Class with no overhead using templates?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, optimization, macros

I am trying to accomplish the following:

1. Object.
2. Debug version of object with extra functionality in functions for tracing purposes.

Now, I currently have a compile-time solution using macros, which resolve to a `do {} while(0)` if the library is not compiled with the proper flag.

I'd LIKE to shift this functionality to being enabled at runtime. What is the best way to do this?

I'd like to do: `Base * obj = (isGlobalDebugEnabled) ? new Debug(...) : new Base(...);` type thing. Am I out of line wanting something like this?

Note, a standard virtual function does not really solve the problem as each function must be duplicated in the derived(debug) version of the object, defeating the purpose.

In addition, the lowest level functions are extremely high volume ( >600 billion calls when profiled) so I want to have a compiled zero-overhead solution for the "base class". The Debug object can be slower, of course.

This is why I thought of templates. **NOTE: I do not have C++11/boost access apart from VS2010 features (basic lambdas, etc)**. Can I do something like

```
template <bool debug = false>
class Object {
    std::enable_if<debug> void printTrace(); // Add functions based on debug/not
};
void Object::doSomething(...){
    <only do this if debug without runtime check> addToTrace(...);
    doTheStuff();
}
```

I saw [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5351/Simulation-of-Virtual-Function-with-Template) which pointed me in the fake-inheritance-with-templates direction, if that helps.

Thank you for your help

AK

**EDIT:** I just realized I may be going about it the wrong way - maybe have the Debug object as the base class, and override the functionality with no-ops in the Regular object. This seems to be a better way. However, I'd still like to avoid the vtable jump due to these high-performance requirements, so I guess my template questions still stand? maybe?

**EDIT2:** As KerrickSB pointed out, an example of use may be more clear:

main exe code:

```
void ComputeSomething() {
    Object * obj = (globalDebugFlag) ? new DebugObject(...) : new Object(...);
    obj->insertElement(elem); // Inserts in Object, Inserts and traces actions in DebugObject
    ...
}
```

where Object is currently a separate DLL and where `globalDebugFlag` is a (proposed) global variable set by a command coming through a separate port than the one that caused ComputeSomething() to be called.

I planned on having global tracing variables that then push the trace back through the port (via a global object that handles this port) for display on the front end tool.

Comment: Are the debug functions always the same, i.e. is there a common "debug interface"?

Comment: If the debug functionality is not interwined, you could simply create debug functions in the Debug derived class in this way: `virtual void foo() { /* debug stuff */ Base::foo(); }`
Otherwise I guess you could simply separate functionality into multiple functions (maybe inline? not sure if you can do that) and use this approach in every spot.

Comment: Could you post a simple example of how you would like to *use* your solution (maybe in pseudo-code)?

Comment: @KerrekSB excellent point, I've added a (hopefully) clearer explanation

Comment: I also realize that the way I just posted it uses a vtable jump. I'd like to avoid that if possible. This is just the type of functionality I want, and am willing to jump through coding hoops (hacks, etc) and sacrifice the maintainability for the speed

Comment: Have you proven that a run-time test slows things down? Branch prediction works really well when the branches always go the same way, especially in a tight loop where it's most likely to matter.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, but to give you a more intuitive understanding why, the actual program is like a server, accepting messages from a client, running 24/7. As the messages come in, they branch throughout the code in various paths and merge at other points. These queries dictate the creation and destruction of these "Objects" and don't follow a set pattern. The lifetime for these is on the order of 10s of milliseconds. Further, these are not called in tight loops, but quite large ones - hundreds of lines long while wrapping function can be called hundreds of millions of times. Am I making sense?

Comment: Note that this does not mean I've obtained definite proof that any option i've considered will slow it down (it most certainly will, but that's besides the point). The undertaking is simply too large for me to make an uninformed (read "good" vs optimal code) decision and profile it. I am aware of vtable costs in isolated tests, and am fairly confident the results will translate into the real program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A run time decision means, by definition, that you do the decision with all its costs *at run time*, as opposed to compile time. You're not gonna get around from that.

However, you could push the checks up the call stack until they are hit infrequently enough for your needs, Of course, then the effect of changing the debugging flag is delayed a bit (how much depends on which checks you elide). Using templates, you can duplicate/specialize the code for debugging and non-debugging versions without duplicating source code.

```
template <bool debug>
class Object {
  void something() {
    // branch on compile-time constant - can be optimized
    if (!debug) return;
    // ...
  }
}

template<bool debug>
useObject(Object<debug> o) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        // statically calls specialized implementation
        o.something();
    }
}

debugEnabled ? useObject(Object<true>()) : useObject(Object<false>());
```

Comment: "A run time decision means, by definition, that you do the decision with all its costs at run time, as opposed to compile time. You're not gonna get around from that." Well it depends how the switch is done. If it's done by swapping a factory from making normal objects to a factory that makes debug objects, then there could be zero overhead for the normal case.

Comment: @bames53 The code using the objects also has to either communicate through a virtual or type-erased interface, or it also has to be duplicated for the two cases.

Comment: @bames53 My retort uses details depending on how you implement that "switch the factory" step and how you *act* differently on those different objects. Assuming, for example, that this factory is a global function pointer and the factory functions return pointers to polymorphic objects, you're back to vtable dispatch for operations on the object. Plus, the call to the factory is indirect, so the factory call can't be inlined or otherwise optimized (no knowledge of potential aliasing).

Comment: Thank you for the excellent post. I realize now that the way I had proposed cannot avoid the vtable jump. I have edited my question to make my intent more clear - if you can suggest an alternative with the additional information, I'd appreciate it. Your current suggestion does not work in my case as the use case involves pointers, and as such cannot (obviously) point to different template types. I guess I'm sort of asking for the impossible haha

Comment: @delnan But if one is already using a factory and polymorphism then adding a version that does debugging adds zero runtime cost. There are also alternatives such as self-modifying code.

Comment: @bames53 If one already uses that, one is using pointless abstractions and getting suboptimal performance as a result. And self-modifying code is not only dangerous (and for that reason, disallowed on some platforms) but also very platform-specific and impossible to do with standard language features. But yes, it's a possibility.

Comment: You're seriously saying there's no possible reason any program would use factories or polymorphism? These are not necessarily pointless abstractions and if they are useful for the program's domain the C++ provides reasonable performance, better than what one often gets with custom polymorphic schemes in C, for example.

Comment: I'm not saying there's no reason. You postulated a situation where a program is using factories and polymorphism, but only has a single implementation. *Then* there is no reason, except perhaps the wish for forward compatibility (which clashes with YAGNI, but reasonable people approach this trade off differently).

Comment: Note that the above approach basically says "replicate the program" -- wrap the part of the program where the debug object is used so that it is generated twice, once with debug and once without.  Then pick which program to run based on run time information.  The advantage is that you write the code once.

Comment: @delnan "but only has a single implementation" I never said anything about only one implementation. If one is using polymorphism then presumably there's more than one, and the debug implementations are in addition to those.

Comment: @bames53 Took you a while to notice ;-) Okay then, gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very basic idea. I'm not sure if it'll generalize or scale, but we can discuss.

```
static bool debug_mode = /* ... */;    // global

class Container
{
    struct ContainerImpl
    {
        virtual ~ContainerImpl() { }
        virtual void insert(int) = 0;
        std::unique_ptr<ContainerImpl> clone() const = 0;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<ContainerImpl> impl;
public:
    Container()
    : impl(debug_mode ? new DebugImpl : new MainImpl)
    { }

    Container(Container const & rhs)
    : impl(rhs.impl->clone())
    { }

    Container(Container && rhs) noexcept
    : impl(std::move(rhs.impl))
    { }

    // also implement assignment


    /*** Main interface ***/

    void insert(int x)
    {
        impl->insert(x);
    }


    /*** Implementations ***/

    struct MainImpl : ContainerImpl { /* main implementation */ };

    struct DebugImpl : MainImpl  // just for example
    {
        virtual void insert(int x)
        {
            // trace insertion
            MainImpl::insert(x);
        }

        std::unique_ptr<ContainerImpl> clone() const
        {
            return { new DebugImpl(*this); }
        }
    };
};
```

Now you can use `Container` as a plain value-type object, and it'll internally use different implementations depending on the flag.

Comment: hmmmm extremely interesting idea - allow me to sleep and come back to this tomorrow so I can better discuss this with you. thanks for your response! also, I've added a further clarifying comment under the OP perhaps giving a little more insight into the environment. EDIT - also, while i sleep, can you explain where exactly you've moved the vtable jump asm instruction? If I am - very quickly - browsing this correctly, is it to the point of object construction, followed by regular func calls in the calling code?

Comment: @AK4749: The virtual dispatch happens in the polymorphic, private ContainerImpl object. This code is basically just a variant of the standard pimpl idiom, with a simple conditional for whether you want the debug version.

Comment: Ah, I understand now how this works. This is a neat trick - have never studied the Opaque Pointer idiom before. However, for a couple reasons scattered around this post, it may not be a valid solution in my case. If I understand this correctly, ptr2Container->insert(x) will still dispatch in order to figure out which implementation to use for each call. Is that correct? I understand the much-improved maintainability for relatively low performance impact, but clients generally do not - nor am I of high enough rank to fight that battle if it comes down to it.

Comment: I do like *very much* this hiding of the debug flag's construction result however. It seems very clean and encapsulated. I may end up doing something similar to this, but with duplicated code in the two implementations to avoid the vtable instructions. The library is not expected to be maintained as heavily as its behavior is well defined, and not easily extended. Some duplication of code can be allowed, I suppose, in order to save those precious cycles.